# updating daterange with part of self

Tags: postgresql

Allright this one is bugging me. Im not that versed in PostgreSQL yet, so it's probably a gap in my knowledge

Consider this:

```
insert into aaa (afdel_id, elev_id,periode,primaer_afd) select :AFD_ID, :ELEV_ID, 
daterange(:PR_DATO, null, '[]'), true
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT afdel_elev_periode_ck
DO UPDATE SET primaer_afd = true, periode = daterange(least(lower(periode), :PR_DATO), null, '[]')
```

it gives me the error "column reference "periode" is ambiguous" propably due to this `periode = daterange(least(lower(periode), :PR_DATO), null, '[]')`
What I want to do is setting the lower part of the daterange [periode] to the first date of lower(periode) and :PR_DATO. (and just set any upper(periode) to null)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ON CONFLICT` so you have access to different versions of a column when you do an `UPDATE`. The original version which is accessed as table_name.col_name and the proposed new value which is exclude.col_name. This is where the error is coming from. Postgres does not know which value you want to use for `periode` in `daterange(least(lower(periode)`.

For more information see:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix the column name with the table name to avoid the ambiguity

```
insert into aaa (afdel_id, elev_id,periode,primaer_afd) 
select :AFD_ID, :ELEV_ID, daterange(:PR_DATO, null, '[]'), true
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT afdel_elev_periode_ck
DO UPDATE 
  SET primaer_afd = true, 
      periode = daterange(least(lower(aaa.periode), :PR_DATO), null, '[]')
```

Comment: Given that the `UPSERT` has turned into an `UPDATE` at this point, using the table name may not be what you want. Doing that would effectively override any new value that is coming in from the `INSERT`. That is why there is the `exclude` 'table'. You can use those values to capture the new value for the field.